# Blazor Validation Error messages and borders show in Black instead of Red

Tags: asp.net, validation, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM project with simple form input. Validation works but the errors show in Black instead of Red.

The errors render black (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0CpC.png)

Here is the html of the Form

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<EditForm Model="memberModel">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="firstName" @bind-Value=memberModel.FirstName />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Surname</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="lastName" @bind-Value=memberModel.Surname />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <InputText id="lastName" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="name@example.com" @bind-Value=memberModel.Email />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">User Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="userName" @bind-Value=memberModel.UserName />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password1">Password</label>
        <InputText type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" @bind-Value=memberModel.Password />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password2">Repeat Password</label>
        <InputText type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" @bind-Value=memberModel.Password2 />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public MemberModel memberModel = new MemberModel();

    public async Task Submit()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Warning!");
    }
}
```

The attributes in my class

```
public class MemberModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    [BsonElement("first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required"),MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Surname must be at least 2 characters long")]
    [BsonElement("surname")]
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>NET6.BlazorWebAssemblyApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-gQhCDsnnnUfaRzD8k1L5llCCV6O9HN09zClIzzeJ8OJ9MpGmIlCxm+pdCkqTwqJ4JcjbojFr79rl2F1mzcoLMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> <!-- Add chart.js reference if Chart components are used in the application. -->
    <script src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I understand that displaying in red is out of the box behaviour, why does mine not though?

Comment: First step.  F12 in the browser and look at CSS being applied.  Where is it coming from?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @MrCakaShaunCurtis. I am long time back end dev new to web. From what I can see this uses blazor.bootstrap.css. I added these references in the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have been implementing a style that does not have the validation errors as red. Bootstrap 5.3.x. through Blazor.Bootstrap.

I overrode the styles like this and it fixed it.

```
.invalid {
    border-color: red;
}
.validation-message {
    color: red;
}
```

Working now:[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvz2.png